# One question about number theory

Tags: number-theory

If $1+a^n$ is prime for some $a\geq 2$ and $n\geq 1$, show that $n$ must be a power of $2$.

I made this;
$a^n + 1$ is prime. Then $a^n$ must be even. Then $a^n=2k$. That's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $a^n$ must be even $\iff a$ must be even

Now if $n$ has an odd factor $f(>1),n= d\cdot f$ (say)

$\displaystyle a^n+1=a^{df}+1=(a^d)^f-(-1)^f$ will be divisible by $a^d-(-1)=a^d+1$ which is definitely $>1$

**References** :

1. [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd)
2. [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b)

Comment: What The fact that it's divisible tells us here? Why is a even?

Comment: @AYARcom, If $a$ is odd, so must be $a^n$. Hence $a^n+1$ will be even and $>2$ for $a\ge2,$ right?  Hence, composite