# How to prove that $4^m + 5^m$ is divisible by 9 when m is an odd number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to use congruence theorems, specifically Euler's Theorem for a proof.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd

Answer (score 9):

$4^m +  5^m \equiv (-5)^m + 5^m \equiv -5^m + 5^m \equiv 0 \mod 9 $

Comment: Just note that if we replace the symbols $4,5$ with $a,b$, and thus mod by $a+b$, the proof generalizes nicely.

Answer (score 4):

No need of them. If $m$ is an odd integer, then:
$$(x+y)\mid (x^m+y^m),$$
since:
$$x^m+y^m = (x+y)(x^{m-1}-\cdots+y^{m-1}).$$
Now just take $x=4$ and $y=5$.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$4^{2m+1} = 4\cdot 16^m\equiv 4(-2)^m \pmod 9$$ and $$5^{2m+1} = 5 \cdot 25^{m} \equiv 5 (-2)^{m} \pmod{9}.$$

Add them toghether to find $4^{2m+1}+5^{2m+1} \equiv 9(-2)^m \equiv 0 \pmod9$.