# $ 1987 \mid \left( n^n + (n+1)^n \right) $

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Problem from the 1987 Leningrad Math Olympiad:

> Is there a positive integer $n$ such that $ n^n + \left( n + 1 \right)^n $ is divisible by $ 1987 $?

The provided solution:

> The answer is yes. Take $ n = 993 $ and we get $ \left( n + n + 1 \right) \mid \left( n^n + (n+1)^n \right) $, so $ 2n + 1 = 1997 $, which gives $ n = 993 $.

My question is: really? How is it obvious that  $ \left( n + n + 1 \right) \mid \left( n^n + (n+1)^n \right) $? Is that a true statement for all $n$? If so, what is the proof? Thanks!

Comment: yes $(x+y) | x^n+y^n$ when $n$ is odd

Comment: Notice $k+ 1 = -k \pmod {2k+1}$. If $s$ is an odd number, you get $k^s + (k+1)^s = k^s + (-k)^s = 0 \pmod {2k+1}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd)

Comment: Well. This question (at least without the solution) is way more interesting than the one I proffered this to be a duplicate of. Having second thoughts, but...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is the following known observation: If $n=2k+1$ then
$$a^{n}+b^n=a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=(a+b)( \mbox{junk} )$$
Thus, for all $n$ odd, $a+b$ divides $a^n+b^n$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Why did I not notice this? I will accept in 11 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

$a+b\mid a^k+b^k$ when $k$ is odd.

Comment: My question was, what is the proof for this?

Comment: Well, no, your question was, why is $n+(n+1)\mid n^n + (n+1)^n$. I reduced it to a theorem I assumed you'd know :)

Comment: Okay, fair enough. +1. :)

Comment: @AhaanRungta $a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\cdots+b^{k-1})$ so $a-b\mid a^k-b^k$. If $k$ is odd then $a+b=a-(-b)\mid a^k-(-b)^k=a^k+b^k$ .

Answer (score 2):

${\bf Hint}\ \  n-m\mid n^k-m^k.\ $ So $\,\ m=-(n\!+\!1),\,\ k\,$ odd
${\rm yields}\ \ 2n\!+\!1\mid n^k\!+(n\!+\!1)^k.\,\ $ Yours is case $\,k=n.$

**Remark** $\ $ The above divisibility can be viewed as a special case of the  Factor Theorem $\, x-y\,\ \mid\,\ f(x)-f(y)\ $ for any polynomial $\,f\,$ or, by the [Polynomial Congruence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\,x\equiv y\Rightarrow f(x)\equiv f(y),\,$ where above $\,f(x) = x^k.$