# Following number is divisible by

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

If $ n = 2009$ , then $N = 2009^n -1982^n -1972^n + 1945^n $ is not divisible by

1. 659
2. 1977
3. 1998
4. 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b/188710)
$$a^m-b^m-c^m+d^m=a^m-b^m-(c^m-d^m)$$ will be divisible by $(a-b,c-d)=P$

Similarly, $$a^m-b^m-c^m+d^m=a^m-c^m-(b^m-d^m)$$ will be divisible by $(a-c,b-d)=Q$

So, $a^m-b^m-c^m+d^m$ will be divisible by $(P,Q)$

As $2009-1982=27=1972-1945,$   our $N$ will be divisible by $(27,27)=?$

As $2009-1972=37=1982-1945,$   our $N$ will be divisible by $(37,37)=?$

So, $N$ will be divisible by $(37,27)=?$

Finally, here $N$ is also even.

Again, As $n=2009$ is odd using [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd),

$$N=2009^n-1982^n-1972^n+1945^n=2009^n-(-1945)^n-\{1982^n-(-1972)^n\}$$

will be divisible by $(2009+1945,1982+1972)=?$

Comment: I got P =27 and Q=37 but they are not divisible by any option

Comment: @AakashKumar, So, N is divisible by $(37,27)=999$  Again, $N$ is even, hence is divisible by $(999,2)=1998$

Comment: How N is even,I cannot understand this

Comment: @AakashKumar, Divide each term by $2$ to find each remainder

Comment: Which term you are talking about

Comment: @Aakash, $2009,1982,1975,1945$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Compute modulo 7. (And the main "miracle" is that only one of the four answers is correct)

Comment: What is modulo ?