# Proof that $3^{105}+4^{105} \equiv 0 \;(\bmod\; 13)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm trying to prove what he title says.
I've found that (i'll type it that way for the sake of using less code i.e using $\vert$ instead of the congruence symbol) $13 \vert 3^3 -1$ and that $13 \vert 4^3 +1$.
I know by the congruence properties that $13 \vert 4^3 + 3^3$
However I don't know how to follow from there, I multiplied by $3^{102}$$4^{102}$ and got that $13 \vert 3^{102} 4^{105}+ 3^{105}4^{102}$ but I don't think this will help me with something.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $3^{105} \equiv (3^3)^{35} \equiv 1^{35} \pmod {13}$.  This is a consequence of how if $a \equiv b \pmod q$ then $a + x \equiv b + x \pmod q$ and $a x \equiv b x \pmod q$.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$3^{105} = (3^{3})^{35} = (27)^{35} \equiv (1)^{35}(\bmod\; 13) = 1$

$4^{105} = (4^{3})^{35} = (64)^{35} \equiv (-1)^{35}(\bmod\; 13) = -1$

Adding both we have

$1+(-1)=0$

QED.

Comment: Hmm I don't really see where FLT was used, I just see that $3^3 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ was used.

Comment: Is $a^k \equiv b^k \;(\bmod\; n)$ derived from Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: @Ovi Thanks. FLT was not used. Error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{105} + 4^{105} = (3^3)^{35} + (4^5)^{21} = 27^{35} + 1024^{21} \equiv 1^{35} + (-3)^{21} = 1 + (-1)(3^3)^7 \\ \equiv -1 + 1 = 0 \pmod {13}$$

Answer (score 1):

Following your way, it is sufficient to establish $$(3^3)^{35}+(4^3)^{35}$$ is divisible by $3^3+4^3$ which is evident from [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by a+b when n is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd)

Answer (score 0):

You can also say that if $n$ is a natural number and **divisible by 3**, say $n=3k$ with **$k$ odd**, then:

$$3^{n}+4^{n}=3^{3k}+4^{3k}=(3^{3})^{k}+(4^{3})^{k}=27^k+64^k\equiv 1^k+(-1)^k=0\,(\ {\rm mod}\ 13)$$

because:  $\ 27\equiv 1 ({\rm mod}\ 13)$ and $\ 64\equiv -1 ({\rm mod}\ 13)$

Comment: This little generalization was suggested in a discussion with my collegue José Eduardo Blazek.

Comment: Obviously, this was already showed by previous answer using $a+b$ divides $a^n+b^n$ when $n$ is odd .