# How to calculate the $\gcd(10^6 +1 , 10^2 +1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I can't really figure out how to approach this question..

I have tried to factor *10^2 +1* out of *10^6 +1* , however, the '*+1*' part makes it difficult.

$10^6 + 1 = (10^2 +1) \cdot 10^3 + 899000$,
$10^2 + 1 = 899000 \cdot ...? $

Here is where I get stuck, because $899000$ is way bigger than $10^2 + 1$..

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use $$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$
I think it must help.

Comment: How it can help?

Comment: @samjoe It can help if you plug in the appropriate value of $x$, such that two of the expressions become $10^2+1$ and $10^6+1$...

Comment: But how does it ensure that $(x+1)$ is indeed the *greatest* common divisor?

Comment: @samjoe We get already that $10^6+1$ is divided by $10^2+1$.

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon What is a greater number than $n=10^2+1$ for which $10^2+1$ is divisible by $n$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Of course, none :) My query is satisfied. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since $10^2+1=101$ is a prime number, you only have two options:

1. $101$ divides $10^6+1$, in which case the gcd is $101$
2. $101$ does not divide $10^6+1$, in which case the gcd is $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!   
How can I find which one of the two options it is?  
Or is this just trying to factor 101 out of 10^6+1

Comment: @R3E1W4 Dividing $1000001$ by $101$ isn't all that hard, is it?

Comment: Ah I see... haha thanks!

Comment: @R3E1W4 I really think you should accept the other answer (by Michael Rozenberg). It's much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "throw rocks at it until it falls off a cliff approach":

$\gcd (10^6 + 1, 10^2 + 1) = \gcd([10^6 + 1] - 10^4(10^2 + 1), 10^2 + 1)$

$=\gcd (-10^4 + 1, 10^2 + 1) = \gcd(-10^4 + 1 + 10^2(10^2 + 1), 10^2 + 1)$

$= \gcd(10^2 + 1,10^2+1) = 10^2 + 1$.

....

There's also the insightful.  $x^n - 1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + .... + x + 1)$ and if $n$ is odd then $x^n + 1 = (x+1)(x^{n-1} - x^{n-2} + .... + x^2 - x + 1)$ and let $x = 10^2$ and $n = 3$ and... oh,... that's Mike Rozenberg's elegant answer... isn't it?