# Is $2^{57} + 1$ is a composite number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove the following: $2^{57} + 1$ is a composite number.

Comment: See here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You must be more explanatory, we don't make homeworks

Comment: @Elborito  it doesn't matter because people will answer it anyway

Comment: @Randall Yes I know, but she can write the context of the question, it is from of a book or a class or Algebra, etc.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can factor $$2^{57}+1 = \left( 2^{19} \right)^3+1 = \left( \left(2^{19} \right)^2 -2^{19} + 1 \right)\left( 2^{19} + 1 \right)$$ where both factors are greater than $1$. Therefore, $2^{57}+1$ is composite.

Answer (score 5):

Yes: $2^{57}+1\equiv(-1)^{57}+1=-1+1=0\mod 3$.