# What should $n$ be equal to, so that $5^{2n+1}2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2}2^{2n+1}$ is completely divisible by $19$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What should $n$ be equal to, so that the number:
$$5^{2n+1}2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2}2^{2n+1}$$
is completely divisible by 19? I broke it into this:
$$20\cdot 2^{n}\cdot 25^{n}+18\cdot 3^{n}\cdot 4^{n}$$ But what should i do next?

Comment: You could test a few small values of $n$ and look for a pattern. If you find a pattern you can try to confirm it by the method of induction.

Comment: Hint: $20\cdot50^{n}+18\cdot12^{n} = (19+1)50^{n}+(19-1)12^{n} = 19(50^{n}+12^{n}) + (50^{n}-12^{n})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so you have shown the expression to be equal to $20\cdot 2^n\cdot 25^n+18\cdot3^n\cdot4^n=20\cdot 50^n+18\cdot12^n$ and as @mwt as shown in comments , write $20=19+1$ and $18=19-1$ to get the expression equal to $19(50^n+12^n)+50^n-12^n$. Now we know that $a^n-b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$ for any natural number $n$. If you don't know that, you can prove it by factorizing $a^n-b^n$.

So $50^n-12^n$ is divisble by $38$ and so $19$ divides the whole expression for any natural number $n$.

Comment: what do you mean by factorizing

Comment: Well, you can divide $a^n-b^n$ by $a-b$ by doing normal division. You will end up with the quotient $\displaystyle a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$. So that means $a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)$.

You can also see [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem#:~:text=In%20algebra%2C%20the%20factor%20theorem,of%20the%20polynomial%20remainder%20theorem.&text=is%20a%20root).) or see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd).

Answer (score 4):

For any natural $n$ we obtain:
$$\begin{aligned}5^{2n+1}2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2}2^{2n+1}&=2^{n+1}\left(10\cdot5^{2n}+9\cdot6^n\right) \\
&= 2^{n+1}\left(10\cdot(6+19)^{n}+9\cdot6^n\right) \\ 
& \equiv2^{n+1}\left(10\cdot6^n+9\cdot6^n\right) \pmod{19} \\ &\equiv 0 \pmod{19}.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: what does ≡ means? seems like you scripted a lot of steps, i really don't get it

Comment: @manabou11 $a\equiv b(\mod k)$ it's the same $a-b$ is divisible by $k$. Also, I added something...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, you can use \pmod{k} for $\pmod{k}$.

Comment: @ABCD Thank you! But it still seems not so good...

Comment: i edited it to make it look more better...

Answer (score 2):

Having gotten to $20\cdot2^n\cdot25^n+18\cdot3^n\cdot4^n$, note that $20\equiv1$ mod $19$ while $18\equiv-1$ and $25\equiv6$. It follows that

$$20\cdot2^n\cdot25^n+18\cdot3^n\cdot4^n\equiv2^n\cdot6^n-3^n\cdot4^n\equiv12^n-12^n\equiv0\mod 19$$

Remark: This approach assumes you have modular arithmetic in your toolbox. (Someone added a tag indicating you do, but it may not be the case.)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction that $20\cdot2^n\cdot25^n+18\cdot3^n\cdot4^n$

$=20\cdot50^{n}+18\cdot12^{n}$ is divisible by $19$.

It's obviously true for $n=0$, since $20+18=38=2\cdot19$.

Now assume $19$ divides $20\cdot50^{n}+18\cdot12^{n}$.

Then $20\cdot50^{n+1}+18\cdot12^{n+1}=50\cdot20\cdot50^{n+1}+12\cdot18\cdot12^{n+1}$

$=12\cdot(20\cdot50^n+18\cdot12^{n})+38\cdot20\cdot50^n$ is divisible by $19$.

QED