# Evaluating $(1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n) \mod 5.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What will be the reminder of (1<sup>n</sup> +2<sup>n</sup> +3<sup>n</sup> +4<sup>n</sup>)/5? Simply (1<sup>n</sup> +2<sup>n</sup> +3<sup>n</sup> +4<sup>n</sup>) mod 5=? **Where n<=10<sup>100000</sup>**.
My idea: The reminder may be 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 when a number is divided by 5.
We can easily calculate it when **n** is too small but when **n**  is too big like  **n<=10<sup>100000</sup>** **how can we calculate it?**

Comment: Use Fermat's little theorem --  $a^4\equiv1\bmod5$ when $\gcd(a,5)=1$ -- to reduce $n$ mod $4$:

Comment: The solution is in the web at many places, e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-value-1n-2n-3n-4n-mod-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $n$ is odd, $$1^n+4^n$$ is divisible by  $1+4$  using [Proof of $a^n+b^n$ divisible by $a+b$ when $n$ is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641443/proof-of-anbn-divisible-by-ab-when-n-is-odd)

If $4\mid n, r^4\equiv1\pmod5$  for  $r=1,2,3,4$ generally for  $(r,5)=1$

If $n\equiv2\pmod4,$

$$1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n\equiv1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2\pmod5\equiv?\pmod5$$

Answer (score 0):

We can reduce $n$ mod $4$ using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),

which indicates that $a^4\equiv1\bmod5$ when $\gcd(a,5)=1$.